# Expected semicolon error after new instance of object

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Why is this giving me an expected symbol error this error? It wants me to put a ";" in between Pokemon and baby on line 4.

```
public Pokemon reproduceWithPokemon(Pokemon otherPokemon){
int chance = (int)(Math.random());
if (chance <= .15){
    return Pokemon baby = new 
         Rapidash(this.getxPos(),this.getyPos(),this.getbounds());
}
return null;
```

Comment: That's not how return works. You can't return an assignment statement, only an expression. What do you think assigning will even accomplish? Just return the new instance and assign `baby` to the return value outside.

Comment: @AndrewLi actually it is possible to return the result of an assignment statement, but not of a variable declaration like above

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Yeah, I should have been clearer. My bad.

Comment: With the given logic, fixing the syntax error will result in always returning a `new Rapidash` because `chance` will always be `0` after assignment. Also you're comparing an `int` to a `double`. The comparison will always be `if (0.0 <= 0.15)`, which is always `true`. You can write the equivalent code by dropping the call to `Math.random`, the variable `chance`, the `if`, and the second `return`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply return the Pokemon object if the chance is less than 15% like so

```
public Pokemon reproduceWithPokemon(Pokemon otherPokemon){
    double chance = Math.random();

    if (chance <= .15){
        return new Rapidash(this.getxPos(),this.getyPos(),this.getbounds());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: as I already commented above, an *assignment statement* **can** be used in a return statement, it is the *local variable declaration* that does not work (just names)

Comment: With this code, the `if` clause will always be `true`.

Comment: wow i did not realize that the code had more problems than the simply the return part. I fixed it @LewBloch

Answer (score 1):

You get that error because that is not how a correct `return` statement looks like. Simply return a *value*:

```
return new Rapidash(this.getxPos(), this.getyPos(), this.getbounds());
```

You *could* do that with an assignment as well (like you have in your code example), but it has to be something like this:

```
Pokemon baby;
return (baby = new Rapidash(this.getxPos(), this.getyPos(), this.getbounds()));
```

But all it does is assign the value to the variable `baby` and then return it, so you don't really gain much from it.

Also your if condition will not work as expected because you're casting the result of `Math.random()` to an int, which will just truncate everything after the decimal point. Since this generates a random number in the interval `[0, 1[`, casting it to int will **always** give you `0`.

Simply turn `chance` into a `double` and drop the cast, then your condition should work as expected:

```
double chance = Math.random();
```

Comment: On the other hand, the idiom of assigning to the variable first, then returning it is useful for debugging, and is almost free. `final Pokemon baby = new Rapidash(this.getxPos(), this.getyPos(), this.getbounds())); return baby;` The `final` reference is optimized almost universally, and allows a debug breakpoint right before the `return`, which is often very, very useful.

Answer (score -1):

```
    public Pokemon reproduceWithPokemon(Pokemon otherPokemon){
int chance = (int)(Math.random());
if (chance <= .15){
    return new 
         Rapidash(this.getxPos(),this.getyPos(),this.getbounds());
}
return null;
```

This is how it should be.

Comment: `chance` will always be assigned `0`. `chance <= 0.15` will promote `chance` to `double`, and will always evaluate `true`, rendering the `if` clause useless. Answers should not promulgate such egregious errors. So this is _not_ how it should be.

Comment: The idea here was to show how return works. The logic is up to him as I had only modified the return statement.  In any case I should be more careful while posting. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you read the Javadocs and find out, @Sachin Kumar? You don't need Stack Overflow to do your own reading for you.